# WiX replace dialog

Tags: wix, wix-extension, wixlib

How may I replace one standard dialog, e.g MaintenanceTypeDlg?

I have a reference to UIExtension.dll and when I add MaintenanceTypeDlg.wxs to my project, I get an error about duplication of dialogs.

Can I replace a single standard dialog without removing the reference and adding all needed .wxs files?