# FilesInUse cannot be modified and CloseApplications does nothing

Tags: wix

I've googled this to death and cannot find a solution that works.

We need to prevent the user from re-installing our app while it's still running.  The standard FilesInUse dialog works but it still allows the user to continue while the app is running and we dont want to force them to reboot - ie, they have to shutdown the app manually.

We tried to create a custom FilesInUse dialog:

1. We include the FilesInUse source and remove the Ignore option
2. Rename the ID of the dialog
3. Change the DialogRef in the Mondo UI
4. Add an suppress for ICE20 because it complains the FilesInUse doesnt exist if we dont do this.

The new dialoag is never used.

If I leave the id of FileInUse unmodified then I get an error about a duplicate dialog.

Ive also tried using utils:CloseApplications but this never does anything.

So:  What is the current thinking on how to do this?

Thanks

PS, I love Wix but it does frustrate me at times :)  Much like the wife...

Comment: Have you got any news on your question? Did you find a solution outside of stackoverflow? I would be interested in it. I want to force an installing user to close all browser sessions. Sounds like being pretty much the same...

Comment: No, never resolved this and I now have a new employer and we dont do desktop apps.  This is one of those mysteries of life that will forever remain unanswered - at least for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to achieve the same thing, I discovered the answer in the related question: [Including modified FilesInUse dialog in WIX project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172455/including-modified-filesinuse-dialog-in-wix-project).

Remove the `DialogRef` entry of `FilesInUse` from the UI file, and replace it with the custom `Dialog` for `FilesInUse` directly in the UI file.